# What's wrong with my code in Java?

Tags: java

I have written a code that is supposed to count the following, 
here some examples:

```
x(2) = 1 * (1+2) = 3
x(4) = 1 * (1+2) * (1+2+3) * (1+2+3+4) = 180
x(5) = 1 * (1+2) * (1+2+3) * (1+2+3+4) * (1+2+3+4+5) = 2700
```

Edit:

Thx a lot so far to everyone!

I didn't expect to get help that fast and precise, really nice :D

Just modified my code now and I no longer get 0 as result (no matter what i typed) which is very good.
But I think there is another mistake left somewhere, 
let's say I type into console 2, I will get 2 as result.
If I type 4, I get 24 as result. For 5 I get 120 and 6 I get 720.
From this I could realize one thing. 
If i divide let's say 720 by 6, I get 120 which is the previous result (of 5).
And if I take result of 5 which is 120 and divide it by 4, I get 24.

```
public class CounIt 
{
    public static int i;
    public static int j;

    public static int b;
    public static int c;

    public static int a (int k)
    {
        j = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
            j = j + 1;
        return j;
    }

    public static int x (int k)
    {
        b = 1;
        for (c = 1; c <= k; ++c)
            b = b * a(c);
        return b;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(x(k));
    }
}
```

Comment: 0 times n = 0. You probably wanted `b = 1;`

Comment: @kocko: Amusingly, in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Whenever faced with something like this, use your debugger to step through the code and watch it run, looking at the values of the variables. See also [*How to debug small programs*](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Instead of initializing the variables locally, why not make a constructor and set the variables to 0

The problem is the second method will return return 0. b = 0 * a(c) = 0...

Comment: You should not be changing the code in your question once you've started getting answers (thus invalidating them). You also should be posting follow-up questions in the answers section. If you have a new question, post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. `b` remains 0 in the function `x(int)`, so this function always returns 0. Shouldn't it be initialised to 1?
2. The function `a(int)` returns the input parameter. Didn't you mean to return `j`?

Also, having single character function names makes your program tricky to read.

Answer (score 1):

Because you initialized b to zero every multiplication of b will give you 0

```
    b = 0;   // Set b to zero
    for (c = 1; c <= k; ++c)
        b = b * a(c);    // b will stay to 0 because b = 0 * a(c);
```

Modify your code to

```
    b = 1;  // <---- Here the modification
    for (c = 1; c <= k; ++c)
        b = b * a(c);
```

To be sure that your code works as expected you should unit test your functions. Take a look at [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) metodology, it will save you a lot of time for bigger projects. And [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html) a link to a nice tutorial to unit tests.

Comment: Tyvm I haven't realized that!
But there is another mistake I think. Let's say I type 2, then i get 2 as result. If I type 4 I get 24 as result. For 5 I get 120.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class CountIt 
{
    public static int i;
    public static int j;

    public static int b;
    public static int c;

    public static int a (int k)
    {
        j = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < k; ++i)
            j = j + 1;
        return j;
    }

    public static int x (int k)
    {
        b = 1;
        for (c = 1; c <= k; ++c)
            b = b * a(c);
        return b;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(x(k));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both functions a and x have errors. Modify functions as below.

**Logically its working**

```
public static int a (int k)
{
        j = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) // changed consition to less than or equal to
            j = j + 1;
        return j; // returns j
}

public static int x (int k)
{
        b = 1; // changed initial value to 1
        for (c = 1; c <= k; ++c)
            b = b * a(c);
        return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is very suitable for recursion:

```
public class SumPyramid {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumPyramid(5));
    }

    public static int sumPyramid(int height) {
        if (height == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return height + sumPyramid(height - 1);
        }
    }
}
```